# Where is the folder of my own app after installing it on my device?

Tags: android, package, directory, apk, where-clause

I cant find the package folder of my own app on my device in the file manager. All the folders of the default apps are there under *android* folder, but not the one of my app that i installed by simply copying my APK into a folder and installing it.

Could you please explain me why I cant find it? It must be there somewhere, as my app is working just fine. Do I have to root my device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A folder like /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/packagename is not automatically created when the app is installed. Neither when it runs the first time. You have to use getExternalFilesDir to determine the path first and use mkdirs to create all directories. A folder /data/data/packagename is created at install but invisible for other apps.